# mixing subscript in a string

Tags: excel, vba

in a VBA excel macro I am using, I have the following code:

```
For k = MinDeg To MaxDeg
        OutputStr = Trim(OutputStr & "a" & Str(k) & " = " & _
                    Str(MyCoe) & " ± " & _
                    Str(MyErr) & Chr(10))
Next k
```

Where "MyCoe" and "MyErr" are given numbers, and "minDeg" and "MaxDeg" are integers.

My question is:

How can I make "Str(k)" appear in the outputstr as **subscript** text?

Comment: Place the unformatted string in a cell and then parse the cell apply the correct font to the `Characters` following each *a*.

Comment: It would depend on **where** you want it to appear as subscript

Answer (score 1):

If Unicode is available in your environment, another option would be to use the subscripted Unicode characters for Str(K).  Making some modifications to Gary's Student code so as to get output in A1:

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
Dim K As Long
Const MinDeg As Long = 10
Const MaxDeg As Long = 13
Dim sK As String, I As Long
Const MyCoe As Long = 3
Const MyErr As Long = 5
Dim OutPutStr As String

For K = MinDeg To MaxDeg

    sK = ""
    For I = 1 To Len(CStr(K))
        sK = sK & ChrW(832 & Mid(CStr(K), I, 1))
    Next I

        OutPutStr = Trim(OutPutStr & "a" & sK & " = " & _
                    Str(MyCoe) & " ± " & _
                    Str(MyErr) & Chr(10))

Next K

Cells(1, 1) = OutPutStr

End Sub
```

---

Note that the subscripted values also appear in the formula bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First I run this simple mod to your code:

```
Sub WhatEverr()
    mindeg = 10
    maxdeg = 13
    mycoe = 3
    myerr = 5
    For k = mindeg To maxdeg
            outputstr = Trim(outputstr & "a" & Str(k) & " = " & _
                        Str(mycoe) & " ± " & _
                        Str(myerr) & Chr(10))
    Next k
    Range("A1").Value = outputstr
End Sub
```

to get this in **A1**:

[image]

Then I run:

```
Sub formatcell()
    Dim i As Long, L As Long, rng As Range
    Dim s As String

    Set rng = Range("A1")
    s = rng.Value
    L = Len(s)

    For i = 1 To L
        ch = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If ch = "a" Then
            rng.Characters(Start:=i + 2, Length:=2).Font.Subscript = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

To apply the format:

[image]

In Excel, this type of character formatting is a property of the `Range` object.  You do not build it into the string like you would in HTML.